# django pk doesn't work for pk value above 9

Tags: django, url, view

Hi i m new in django and i m trying to figure out now for hour , why does primary key(pk) doesn't work correctly to update my form for value above 9. Its say that The current path, tache_app/TacheUpdate/15, didn't match any of these. I have check numerous time the id 15 and it does exist. 
My guess is that primary key (pk) doesn't work for value above 9.
Here is my code please help to figure it out. Appologies for my english it isn't so good. i live in france.

in my urls.py file

```
"""Mettre les urls pour la tache app etc etc etc """
from django.urls import path 
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('tache_ajouter/' , views.tache_ajouter , name='tache_ajouter' ),
    url(r'^TacheCreate$', views.TacheCreate.as_view(), name='TacheCreate'),     

    url(r'^TacheUpdate/(?P<pk>\d)$', views.TacheUpdate.as_view(), name='TacheUpdate'),

    url(r'^TacheDelete/(?P<pk>\d)$', views.TacheDelete.as_view(), name='TacheDelete'),  

]


class TacheUpdate(UpdateView):
    """
     Creation d une view afin de modifier les 
    d une tache 
    """
    model = Tache 
    template_name = "tache_app/edition.html"
    fields = "__all__"
    from_class = TacheForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tache')
```

if you need anything please ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\d` regex part matches *one* digit, not multiple ones. In order to match multiple digits, you add a `+` quantifier. This `+` quantifier means "one or more", hence `\d+` means one or more digits. So your urls should look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tache_ajouter/', views.tache_ajouter, name='tache_ajouter'),
    url(r'^TacheCreate$', views.TacheCreate.as_view(), name='TacheCreate'),
    url(r'^TacheUpdate/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.TacheUpdate.as_view(), name='TacheUpdate'),
    url(r'^TacheDelete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.TacheDelete.as_view(), name='TacheDelete'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using Django 2.x, it's good idea to use path() instead och url(). It has a more verbose syntax, which I find makes it harder to make mistakes.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tache_ajouter/', views.tache_ajouter, name='tache_ajouter'),
    path('TacheCreate', views.TacheCreate.as_view(), name='TacheCreate'),
    path('TacheUpdate/<int:pk>', views.TacheUpdate.as_view(), name='TacheUpdate'),
    path('TacheDelete/<int:pk>', views.TacheDelete.as_view(), name='TacheDelete'),
]
```